# Multiplication of a list and list of list

Tags: python, list, matrix-multiplication

Mathematically I am trying to do a xij * yi multiplication. In Python, I need to multiply x and y lists as below:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = [10,100,1000]

xy = [[] for i in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
   for j in range(3):
       xy[i][j] += [y[i] * x[i][j]]
```

However, I get "list index out of range" error  while I expect to have the output as following:

```
xy = [[10, 20, 30],[400, 500, 600],[7000, 8000, 9000]]
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close. The issue was that you were using double indices `[i][j]` to refer to your nested lists. You have to just use the index `i`. The rest of your code is perfectly fine.

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = [10,100,1000]

xy = [[] for i in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        xy[i] += [y[i] * x[i][j]]

# [[10, 20, 30], [400, 500, 600], [7000, 8000, 9000]]
```

**Alternative is** to use `append`

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        xy[i].append(y[i] * x[i][j])
```

**Alternative using NumPy**

```
import numpy as n
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
y = np.array([10,100,1000])
xy = (x.T*y).T
```

Comment: Brilliant catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve the problem,

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
y = [10,100,1000]
xy = []
for i in range(3):
    xy.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        xy[i].append(y[i]*x[i][j])
print (xy)
```

In python, use 'list.append()' to add value to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `numpy` library's `multiply()` function to solve this problem with the help of List comprehensions -

```
import numpy as np
list([np.multiply(x[i],y[i]).tolist() for i in range(len(y))])
    [[10, 20, 30], [400, 500, 600], [7000, 8000, 9000]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple list comprehensions:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = [10,100,1000]

xy = [[y[i] * j for j in lst] for i, lst in enumerate(x)]
print(xy)
```

The output:

```
[[10, 20, 30], [400, 500, 600], [7000, 8000, 9000]]
```